# How to split table row for fixed rows with timeinterval jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with tables, and I have a page which is not scrolling, and one solution was to show in a table values which are fitting on the page, this value **12**, if in table **more then 12 rows**, then it's **first 12 rows** hide, and show other.

For now I created a script which hides and shows rows, but the problem is when it's going to **second "page"** header of table is hide, and some CSS styles are not working.

```
var elements = $("table tr");
var pages = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var showNext = function (index) {
        console.log(index)
        if (index >= elements.length) {
            index = 0;
            pages = 0;
            location.reload();
        }
        pages++
        elements.hide().slice(index, index + 12).show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            showNext(index + 8);

        }, 3000);
    }
    showNext(0);
});
```

Comment: can you share the html of the table header. you can try to use "thead" and "tbody" to build your table and make  use of them to hide/show only "tr"s of the "tbody".

Comment: @Tuckbros thanks for answer, but i fix

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, problem was then **thead** have **tr** and i declarate then hide **tr** by 3 sec.
Added to **html tbody**

`<tr class="rows-data">`

```
var elements = $(".rows-data");
var pages = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    var showNext = function (index) {
        console.log(index)
        if (index >= elements.length) {
            index = 0;
            pages = 0;
            location.reload();
        }
        pages++
        elements.hide().slice(index, index + 11).show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            showNext(index + 8);

        }, 3000);
    }
    showNext(0);
});
```